# Red text Highlight in IDA Pro

Tags: ida

Why do some command in IDA have red text highlight around them?
e.g.
[image]

Answer (score 2):

According to [HexRays IDA support](https://www.hex-rays.com/products/ida/support/idadoc/615.shtml), this means an error. In IDA help (press `F1`), under the `Problems List` header you have the list of possible problems encountered during analysis. In your case it seems to be `BADSTACK`, which means:

> The value of the stack pointer at the end of the function is different
>           from its value at the start of the function. [...] The most probable cause is that stack tracing has failed.

You will see each line causing this problem in the `List of problems` window.

The description how to fix this problem is included in the IDA help as well, below the problem description.