# What the meaning of RED dq in .data?

Tags: ida

I'm new to IDA.

Refer here: [Red text Highlight in IDA Pro](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/21140/red-text-highlight-in-ida-pro)

But I can't find any useful in Problem Window.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case, auto-analysis has decided that the `QWORDs` at those locations should be displayed as pointers, but the concrete data value, `0`, is not a valid pointer within the binary's address space.

Comment: So, should I ignore it?

Comment: Yes, it's not important here.